# Unhandled exception thrown

Tags: c++, exception

I'm new to c++ coding.
I'm tring to create a menu driven program for a banking account but it throws and exception after getting an output from the program.

If someone can please explain it in simple terms it would be really helpful since I have no knowledge about exception throwing.

The error in VS was:

> *Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation
> _Pnext was 0xB46A2C*

```
void Data::AccData()
{
    cout << "Enter New Account Number : ";
    cin >> accountnumber;
    cout << "Enter Username : ";
    cin >> username;
b:
    cout << "Enter Account Type (C/S) : ";
    cin >> choice;
    choice = toupper(choice);
a:
    if (choice == 'C')
    {
        cout << "Enter Initial Balance : ";
        cin >> balance;
        if (balance < 1000)
        {
            cout << "Initial balance should be greater than 1000$ for Checking account! ";
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
            system("cls");
            goto a;
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 'S')
    {
        cout << "Enter Initial Balance : ";
        cin >> balance;
        if (balance < 500)
        {
            cout << "Initial balance should be greater than 500$ for Saving account! ";
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
            system("cls");
            goto a;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error! Choose S or C. ";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
        system("cls");
        goto b;
    }
    system("cls");
}

void Data::ShowAccData()
{
    cout << "Account Number : " << accountnumber << endl;

    cout << "Account Information ." << "\n" << endl;

    cout << "Account Number : " << accountnumber << endl;
    cout << "Name of Account Holder : " << username << endl;
    cout << "Account Type : " << choice << endl;
    cout << "Account Balance : " << balance << endl;

    system("cls");
}

void Data::ShowAccDataAll()
{
    cout << accountnumber << "\t\t " << username << "\t\t " << choice << "\t\t" << balance << endl;
}


void Input()
{
    Data d;
    ofstream file("data.txt", ios::binary | ios::app);
    d.AccData();
    file.write(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&d), sizeof(Data));
    file.close();
}

void Output()
{
    Data d;
    ifstream file("data.txt", ios::binary);
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&d), sizeof(Data)))
    {
        d.ShowAccData();
    }
    file.close();
}

void Search()
{
    Data d;
    int acc;
    cout << "Input account number : ";
    cin >> acc;
    ifstream file("data.txt", ios::binary);
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&d), sizeof(Data)))
    {
        if (d.accountnumber == acc)
        {
            d.ShowAccData();
        }
    }
}

void Display_All()
{
    Data d;
    ifstream file("data.txt", ios::binary);
    cout << "\n\n\t\tACCOUNT HOLDER LIST\n\n";
    cout << "====================================================\n";
    cout << "A/c no.      NAME           Type             Balance\n";
    cout << "====================================================\n";
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&d), sizeof(Data)))
    {
        d.ShowAccDataAll();
    }
    file.close();

    system("pause");
}

void Intro();
void Menu();


int main()
{
    Intro();
    Menu();

    int ch;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nPlease Enter the option that u wish : ";
        cin >> ch;
        if (ch == 1)
        {
            Input();
        }
        else if (ch == 2)
        {
            Output();
        }
        else if (ch == 3)
        {
            Search();
        }
        else if (ch == 4)
        {
            Display_All();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Choose valid options";
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
            system("cls");
            Menu();
        }
        system("cls");
        cin.get();
    } while (ch != 8);
}


void Intro()
{
    cout << "============================================";
    cout << "\n********************************************";
    cout << "\n\n\n\t\t  BANK";
    cout << "\n\n\t\tMANAGEMENT";
    cout << "\n\n\t\t  SYSTEM";
    cout << "\n\n\n\nMADE BY : Sakchyam Shrestha";
    cout << "\nThe British College, Kathmandu";
    cout << "\n********************************************";
    cout << "\n============================================";

    cin.get();
    system("cls");
}

void Menu()
{
    cout << "==================================" << endl;
    cout << "**********************************" << endl;
    cout << "\n1.Create Account." << endl;
    cout << "2.Modify Account." << endl;
    cout << "3.Show All Account Information." << endl;
    cout << "8.Exit\n" << endl;
    cout << "==================================" << endl;
    cout << "**********************************" << endl;

    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, you need to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In any case it seems you are trying to access memory that's no longer available.

Comment: i tried to do one at a time. the input works fine. then when i put the output and showaccdata 
it throws the exception

Comment: can u please point out what that is?

Comment: `file.write(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&d), sizeof(Data));` - that will only work for POD classes, but I suspect your `Data` class has `std::string` members. That won't work.

Comment: @rustyx yes the username is using string.
so what should i change it to ?

Comment: @SakchyamShrestha it means exactly that, you are accessing memory that you are not allowed to, the reasons for that are not entirely clear, rustyx may have pinpointed the cause. in his comment.

Comment: @SakchyamShrestha, try it with a C style char array, if it fixes the issue you'll know what's wrong.